# Why does it show up a null in the textarea twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I type in the title it shows up as null even though it is there. Also the textarea shows up twice. Thank you any help is appreciated. I feel like I need to convert it to something for it actually read, but I am just a begineer.

I have tried parsing it to JSON,but feel free to show me how it is properly done.

Sorry for my English

```
var title_s = document.getElementById("TitleSearch");
var titlejson = JSON.parse(title_s);
var teststring = "test";
//This is to intialize everything and auth. with the firebase server
var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyB9p1VvVfhnbrcDwUKUuSqw9aQsqnDi4nQ",
        authDomain: "html5project-870df.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://html5project-870df.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "html5project-870df",
        storageBucket: "html5project-870df.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "54935462861"
      };
//firebase.initializeApp(config);
//checks if it has been init
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({});
}
//declare variables
var database = firebase.database();
//tells where the items are going to be 
var Rootref = database.ref().child("users");
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
//var Rootref1 = database.ref().child("users").child("id: 113295907411766134791")/*.child("trans")*/;

//used to retrieve data 
Rootref.on("child_added",snap => { 
    //gets the child of titles stores it as variable
  var transcript_title = snap.child("titles").val();
    //var transcript_title = (snap.val() && snap.val().titles);
    //gets the actual title and stores it as a var
    //var transcript = snap.child(transcript_title).val();

  $('#transcrip').val(snap.child('users/id: 107621796826103613669'))
    //jquery - way to add html elemnts with javascript

     snap.child("titles").forEach(function(titleSnap) {
  $("#read").append('<h4 id = "clicked">'+titleSnap.val()+'</h4>');
})
  console.log(teststring);
  $( "#TitleButton" ).click(function() {
     var search = snap.child(title_s).val();


  $("#ReadHere").append('<textarea placeholder="Shows up right here" col="50" row="10">'+search+'</textarea>');




  });
        //$("#read").append('<h4 >Test</h4>');

    //when button view was clicked it will show the transcriptiodn






 });
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Calling every thing required-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="54935462861-sedlkvk3ufqujgpo2hmevectur8p4o2u.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>


      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyB9p1VvVfhnbrcDwUKUuSqw9aQsqnDi4nQ",
        authDomain: "html5project-870df.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://html5project-870df.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "html5project-870df",
        storageBucket: "html5project-870df.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "54935462861"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    <!--Title on top left-->

    <h1>View your Transcriptions</h1>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="read.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="TitleSearch">
    <button id = "TitleButton">Search</button>
    <center>

    <ul id="read">

    </ul>
   </center>
   <div id = "ReadHere">
  </div>

   <!--When clicked on you view it here-->
   <h1>Viewed Right Here</h1>
   <p id = "transcrip"></p>   
  </body>
</html>
```

```
{
  "users" : {
    "id: 110753432956858279660" : {
      "Test" : "He",
      "Test2" : "He",
      "titles" : {
        "201920201828" : "Test",
        "201920202259" : "Test2"
      }
    },
    "id: 113295907411766134791" : {
      "test" : {
        "text" : "text"
      },
      "test3" : {
        "text" : "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: perhaps `snap.child(title_s).val()` isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: I figured out that title_s needs to be converted to a string. How do I do that?

Comment: what is `title_s` now? Oh, it's an input element ... you'll want `title_s.value`

Comment: @SaiVeeramachaneni any reason why the code does `snap.child("titles")` everywhere else except here: `var search = snap.child(title_s).val()` ?

Comment: @SaiVeeramachaneni I tried a minimal example without firebase https://jsfiddle.net/raghav710/L37e0r42/ and it works all fine. Can you try editing the fiddle and see whats going on? I think like others mentioned, snap.child is not what you think it is, maybe try adding a console.log to see the value